# Azure Blob Service: Weird TLS 1.2 issue -- Looking for suggestions to investigate it

Tags: windows, azure, networking, azure-blob-storage, tls1.2

So, I've encountered a weird situation and am wondering whether you may have some suggestions as to how to investigate it...

I have a C# app that connects to Azure Blob Services using the latest SDK and TLS 1.2.  When I am at home and on the Internet, I am able to upload files to blob storage without any issues.  However, when I go into our office, using the same app on an office computer, I get a connection failure.  I am able to access the Internet through a browser.

The networking is as simple as at my home... ISP connection, router/firewall, my computer.

I cannot imagine why enabling TLS1.2 would suddenly make my app not work in the office, but still work at home.  Based on these tests, it seems like a NIC issue or an infrastructure issue at the office, but I have never heard of a NIC or router blocking TLS 1.2 outside of a VPN connection. There is no VPN involved.

I am planning on directly connecting my computer to the company's Internet connection, configuring the nic for the wan, and see what happens.  If it works, then there must be something strange going on with the company's router (nothing elaborate; netgear, or such).

Has anyone encountered this issue?  Seems really odd to me...

Thanks for your time and interest,

Mike

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue. Can you test with Google DNS 8.8.8.8 https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Answer (score 0):

•   It is not an issue with enabling of **TLS 1.2 on your office network or your home network or even your Azure blob storage**, it is basically related to the communication over **SMB TCP port 445 from your local system to the mapped Azure blob storage on your system**.

On your home network, you were able to access the blob storage and able to upload files in it because your **ISP has enabled outbound communication over SMB TCP port 445 on his firewall and gateway server over the internet** and thus, you were able to access the mapped Azure blob storage and upload files in it. But the same case is not valid for in your office network as it being a protected one, outbound communication over SMB TCP port 445 is restricted and not allowed.

•   To test whether communication over TCP SMB port 445 can happen or not, I would request you to execute the below powershell command and check the results thereafter: -

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 445 -ComputerName somestoragexxx.file.core.windows.net
```

`If this TCP 445 connectivity fails, then you could check with your ISP or your on-premises office network security is blocking communication over outbound port 445. Please note that you should open the outbound port instead of inbound port 445`.

[image: Powershell results]

Kindly refer to the documentation link below for details to know the different ways to access files in Azure files: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq#general

Also, refer to the link below for knowing the Azure routing mechanism to reach the resources hosted on Azure: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#default

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response.  We will follow the steps that you've suggested and post back here.

Comment: Do let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: Hi @ABitofHelp, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.